# Images for command buttons in footer facet

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

I currently have two command buttons in the footer / header facets - I am trying to have images in those buttons.
Using property inspector I am able to add images for these buttons - but they show up very tiny - no matter whatever the size of image.

Is there a way I can adjust the size of this image display in the property inspector or any where else please?

Comment: @pnuts Good job for editing the [adf] tag to [oracle-adf] but most (all?) of these questions also need the [oracle] tag removing. I've done a few but can't do them all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider styling the Command Buttons or Use Image Link instead